# Keyboard is not opening automatically on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile

I'm using React-Simple-Chatbot (https://github.com/LucasBassetti/react-simple-chatbot) for a web based chatbot. When a user input is prompted, the input field is focused. On Android this works well and opens the keyboard. On iPhone, it does not open the keyboard automatically, the user has to click the input field, then it opens.

The input field is from the styled-components library. I forked the project, to not only focus but also click the input field.

```
chatbot.input.focus();
chatbot.input.click();
```

How can I use Javascript to open the keyboard on iPhone Safari?